# Che tempo verbale devo usare in queste interrogative indirette?

Tags: verbs, tenses

Qualcuno mi può dire quale di queste due frasi è corretta e perché? Ho usato "volevo" come imperfetto di cortesia.

- Volevo chiederle se dovevo risostenere la prova oppure se potevo tenere il voto precedente.
- Volevo chiederle se dovessi risostenere la prova oppure se potevo (potessi?) tenere il voto precedente.

Answer (score 3):

Entrambe le costruzioni suonano male: sono troppo “umili” e soprattutto eccedono inutilmente in subordinate un po' legnose.

Basterebbe usare un semplice presente indicativo (“se devo”), altrimenti sembra che tu stia parlando di un evento passato e quindi, semmai, direi “volevo chiederle se devo etc.”

Io, però, scriverei semplicemente “devo sostenere di nuovo la prova oppure posso tenere il voto precedente?”, non dimenticando, piuttosto, di cominciare e finire il messaggio in un modo sensato (“Gentile professore ... Un cordiale saluto” o simili) e di specificare chi sei e a che corso ti riferisci. (Certo, è una cosa ovvia, ma ho esperienza, in ambito universitario e altrove, di persone che danno per scontato che l'interlocutore sia un telepate e sappia di cosa stanno parlando.)

<sub>Infine – opinione personalissima – l'imperfetto di cortesia è ampiamente usato e non ha niente che non vada, ma la mia prima reazione, leggendolo, è sempre: “D'accordo, volevi la tal cosa. E ora? Non la vuoi più?”</sub>

Comment: A mio avviso, la risposta è corretta se si sta parlando direttamente con la persona a cui si vuole fare la domanda («Buongiorno! Volevo chiederle se devo sostenere...») ma se si tratta di un discorso indiretto, propenderei per il congiuntivo sull'indicativo ("Andai dalla professoressa perché volevo chiederle se dovessi sostenere...").